# Background Image Colors not Showing Up Correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, graphics

I have a background image created by my designer in photoshop. I convert it to png-24, and have two files, one for retina display at 640 x 920, and one for normal display at 320 x 460 (and which I name correctly with @2x). When I implement it on the iPhone 4, it doesn't render correctly (the color is much darker), however when I put it on the iPhone5 it works fine. The size of the file is 608 KB.

I've tried changing the file type to png8 or JPEG (with the lowest quality) and still no luck. I've tried removing the color profile as per this link: [Removing Color Profiles in PhotoShop](http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/) but still no luck.

This is what the image looks like:

[image]
Anyone know what could be going wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: See this uploaded image with Safari from the two iPhones. It should show the difference.

Comment: @larme - I checked that and the difference is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look on a blog a a guy was saying that the iPhone 5 has an increase of 44% in colour saturation. Don't know if this is why you are getting this issue, but from what I have read this can make images on the iPhone 4 look a lot duller then they are meant to be.

Source : http://prometheus.med.utah.edu/~bwjones/2012/09/iphone-5-display-vs-iphone-4-display/

Answer (score 1):

As a test, find another image with likely colors and test it in both iphones example: 
[This Image + Here](http://www.ebibleteacher.com/sites/default/files/powerpoint-backgrounds/1/praisepix-grain1.jpg?1310970418)

Maybe it's just a matter of  brightness or color balance adjustments on the iphone4. If it's so, then in PhotoShop with the image's layer already selected on the tab Image/Adjustments you'll find some tools that will help you, like adding exposure or bright.

Comment: Thanks. I did test that image and it looked different on the iPhone4 as well (the iPhone5 seemed to do it correctly). Just kind of seems hard to believe to me that the iPhone4 can't process that image exactly as intended, when it does a nice job with a lot of other type of photos.